# Raspberrypi4B: Unable to establish a BLE connection between RPi4B and Ubuntu Laptop

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth, ubuntu, bluez

I am unable to establish an ble connection between my Raspberrypi4B and Laptop. Configuration is as below:

Laptop: Ubuntu-20.04.2 LTS, bluez version: 5.53
Raspberrypi4B: Ubuntu-21.04 bluez version: 5.56

Bluetoothctl logs @Raspberrypi4B:

```
nagesh@nagesh-desktop:~$ sudo bluetoothctl
[sudo] password for nagesh: 
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller DC:A6:32:F2:CB:46 Pairable: yes
[bluetooth]# info 6C:6A:77:48:40:08
Device 6C:6A:77:48:40:08 (public)
    Name: root1-Nitro-AN515-55
    Alias: root1-Nitro-AN515-55
    Class: 0x0000010c
    Icon: computer
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: no
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d053A
[bluetooth]# connect 6C:6A:77:48:40:08
Attempting to connect to 6C:6A:77:48:40:08
[CHG] Device 6C:6A:77:48:40:08 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 6C:6A:77:48:40:08 ServicesResolved: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotAvailable
[CHG] Device 6C:6A:77:48:40:08 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device 6C:6A:77:48:40:08 Connected: no
[bluetooth]#
```

btmon logs @Raspberrypi4B: as attached

I see in the btmon ouptut, always connection is terminated but no reason is present which specifies the cause for it.

Initially i was using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on my Raspberrypi4b which i later upgraded to 21.04 but still no luck. Couple of posts pointed to bug in bluez which was pretty old and i am assuming would have already fixed in the bluez 5.56 version.

Can someone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                                                #37 [hci0] 48.886867
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 12
        Count: 1
< ACL Data TX: Handle 12 flags 0x00 dlen 12                                                                                                                                           #38 [hci0] 50.627130
      L2CAP: Disconnection Request (0x06) ident 5 len 4
        Destination CID: 64
        Source CID: 64

Comment: > ACL Data RX: Handle 12 flags 0x02 dlen 12                                                                                                                                           #39 [hci0] 50.644660
      L2CAP: Disconnection Response (0x07) ident 5 len 4
        Destination CID: 64
        Source CID: 64
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                                                                #40 [hci0] 50.886900
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 12
        Count: 1

Comment: < HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3                                                                                                                                        #41 [hci0] 52.661019
        Handle: 12
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                                                                                             #42 [hci0] 52.661672
      Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)

Comment: > HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4                                                                                                                                        #43 [hci0] 52.746521
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 12
        Reason: Connection Terminated By Local Host (0x16)

Comment: @ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                                                                                                                                {0x0001} [hci0] 52.746586
        BR/EDR Address: 6C:6A:77:48:40:08 (Intel Corporate)
        Reason: Connection terminated by local host (0x02)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the root cause of this issue. Thanks to help from colleagues and bluez folks.
The problem is need to register a profile in bluetoothctl @ RPi and initiate a connect from Laptop did the trick.

Change @ RPi:

```
nagesh@nagesh-desktop:~$ sudo bluetoothctl
[sudo] password for nagesh: 
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller DC:A6:32:F2:CB:46 Pairable: yes
[bluetooth]# info 6C:6A:77:48:40:08
Device 6C:6A:77:48:40:08 (public)
    Name: root1-Nitro-AN515-55
    Alias: root1-Nitro-AN515-55
    Class: 0x0000010c
    Icon: computer
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: no
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d053A
[bluetooth]#  menu gatt
[bluetooth]#  register-service 0xaaaa
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
        /org/bluez/app/service0
        0xaaaa
        Unknown
[/org/bluez/app/service0] Primary (yes/no): yes
[bluetooth]#  register-characteristic 0xbbbb read
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
        /org/bluez/app/service0/chrc0
        0xbbbb
        Unknown
[/org/bluez/app/service0/chrc0] Enter value: 0xc
[bluetooth]#  register-application
[CHG] Primary Service (Handle 0x0013)
        /org/bluez/app/service0
        0xaaaa
        Unknown
[CHG] Characteristic (Handle 0x0015)
        /org/bluez/app/service0/chrc0
        0xbbbb
        Unknown
[CHG] Controller CC:C0:79:B3:E4:0C UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller CC:C0:79:B3:E4:0C UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller CC:C0:79:B3:E4:0C UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller CC:C0:79:B3:E4:0C UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller CC:C0:79:B3:E4:0C UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller CC:C0:79:B3:E4:0C UUIDs: 0000aaaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller CC:C0:79:B3:E4:0C UUIDs: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller CC:C0:79:B3:E4:0C UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Application registered
[CHG] Controller CC:C0:79:B3:E4:0C UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller CC:C0:79:B3:E4:0C UUIDs: 00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller CC:C0:79:B3:E4:0C UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller CC:C0:79:B3:E4:0C UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller CC:C0:79:B3:E4:0C UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller CC:C0:79:B3:E4:0C UUIDs: 0000aaaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller CC:C0:79:B3:E4:0C UUIDs: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Controller CC:C0:79:B3:E4:0C UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

@Laptop run bluetoothctl, scan for devices, once  BD address is found, pair using the BD address and then connect using the BD address and the connection would be successful.